# Benefits of mysql trigger to workaround Innodb lack of Fulltext search

Tags: mysql, triggers, innodb, myisam

I have a myISAM table with 2.5 million and rising rows.   It is myisam as I require FullText searching.

Having done some research on stackoverflow I'm looking into creating the table again as a InnoDB table and then creating a copy in myISAM.  Then I will create triggers which will replicate any changes in the innodb table to the myisam table.

The innodb table will function better as it works transactionally and doesn't lock the whole table when it is written to or updated.

My question is:  Will I see much benefit in the myisam table as surely it is going to be written to as often as before because every write to the innodb table will result in a subsequent write to the myisam.

Any suggestions, or other ideas gratefully received.

Brett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using triggers to copy from MyISAM to InnoDB has the risk of creating inconsistent data, when transactions are rolled back.

A better idea might be to install a full text search engine like Sphinx that can work with InnoDB tables.

Another idea would be to synchronise MyISAM with InnoDB periodically using event scheduler. You risk that full text search would return stale data, but on the other hand this should have less of an impact on performance, and at least you know data is consistent after each sync.

Also some good news: starting with MySQL 5.6 InnoDB gets full text searches.

Comment: Thanks, am now using 5.6 and fulltext seems to be working fine on Innodb table

Comment: Excellent! Yay for early adopters :)